# How to Join JSON table with another relational table on json array elements oracle12c?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Using Oracle Database 12c, I have a JSON structure like below.

This query could not return results, though matching records are available in account and ACCOUNTDETAILS table (role=B is second element in parties array).

the same query works when I query for act.ROLE ="A" (first element in parties array).

```
Accounts TABLE

{
"id":"1223",
"parties":[
{
"crossReference":[
 {
    "crsrefvalue":"z123A",
   ---
 }
                              ],
                 "role":"A"
},
{
"crossReference":[
    {
       "crsrefvalue":"z123B",
      ---
}
],
             "role":"B"
}
  ]
}


wanted to join this account table with ACCOUNTDETAILS(columns crsrefvalue,crsrefname) on value account.crsrefvalue=ACCOUNTDETAILS.crsrefvalue and account.parties.role="B"

json query is like below
With ACCT  AS (
SELECT  ID, crsrefvalue, ROLE  from account,
  JSON_TABLE(JSON,’$’ COLUMNS(ID PATH ‘$.ID’,
       NESTED PATH ‘$.PARTIES[*]’ COLUMNS(ROLE PATH ‘.ROLE’, NESTED PATH ‘$.crossReference[*]’  COLUMNS(crsrefvalue PATH ‘$.crsrefvalue’)))) JS_TAB
)   

SELECT  FROM  ACCOUNTDETAILS dtls, ACCT  act where act.crsrefvalue= dtls.crsrefvalue and act.ROLE ="B"

**problem 1)** this query could not return result though matching records are available in account and ACCOUNTDETAILS table.(role=B is second element in parties array)
the same query works when i query for act.ROLE ="A"(first element in parties array)
```